# Trying to get axios-auth-refresh working with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to get axios-auth-refresh working, to ensure that my requests always have a valid auth token, but as far as I can tell the Axios request isn't continuing after axios-auth-refresh intercepts it.

I'm pretty new to JS development, so not sure if I've missed something obvious. I've looked through the [documentation](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh), but can't see any major differences in my implementation.

I'm running Node v13.2.0, v2.2 (latest) of `axios-auth-refresh`, and v0.18.1 of `axios`

My code is as follows:

```js
require('axios-debug-log');
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosauthrefresh = require('axios-auth-refresh');

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.example.com/api/v1.0',
});

let authToken = '';

const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => {
    console.log('Intercepting auth');
    instance
        .post('/auth/login/', {
            username: process.env.USER,
            password: process.env.PASS,
            skipAuthRefresh: true,
        })
        .then((tokenRefreshResponse) => {
            authToken = tokenRefreshResponse.data.token;
            failedRequest.response.config.headers.Authorization = `Token ${authToken}`;
            console.log(`Auth token: ${authToken}`);
            return Promise.resolve();
        });
};

function getAuthToken() {
    if (authToken) {
        console.log(`Token exists: ${authToken}`);
        return `Token ${authToken}`;
    }
    return null;
}

instance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    console.log(`Requesting ${request.url}`);
    const token = getAuthToken();
    if (token) {
        request.headers.Authorization = token;
    }
    return request;
});

axiosauthrefresh.default(instance, refreshAuthLogic);

module.exports = {
    instance,
};
```

I make a request like this:

```js
// nmcapi.js
const request= require('./request');
async function GetFolderInfo(volumeID, filerID, path) {
  try {
    const refreshResponse = await request.instance.get(`/volumes/${volumeID}/filers/${filerID}/path/${path}`);
    console.log(`Refresh triggered: ${path}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

// interval.js
const nmcapi = require('./nmcapi.js');
const info = await GetFolderInfo('examplevolumeid', 'examplefilerid', 'examplepath')
```

And this is what I get as output:

```
Requesting /volumes/examplevolumeid/filers/examplefilerid/path/examplepath
  axios GET /volumes/examplevolumeid/filers/examplefilerid/path/examplepath +1ms
  axios Error: Request failed with status code 401 (GET https://api.example.com/api/v1.0/volumes/examplevolumeid/filers/examplefilerid/path/examplepath) +265ms
Intercepting auth
Requesting /auth/login/
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at f (/home/sean/data-reports/node_modules/axios-auth-refresh/dist/index.min.js:1:1718)
    at /home/sean/data-reports/node_modules/axios-auth-refresh/dist/index.min.js:1:2719
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Object.GetFolderInfo (/home/sean/data-reports/server/nmcapi.js:29:29)
    at /home/sean/data-reports/server/interval.js:25:18
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Object.intervalFunc (/home/sean/data-reports/server/interval.js:36:18)
  axios POST /auth/login/ +16ms
  axios 200 OK (POST https://api.example.com/api/v1.0/auth/login/) +561ms
Auth token: 17412724ef5169eaab8502a9851480741e606ffa
```

As far as I can tell, the `refreshAuthLogic` function is working properly (because it returns a new auth token), but everything stops after that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had missed an important point, the `refreshAuthLogic` function actually needs to return the axios instance `instance`.

The working implementation is:

```js
const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => {
    return instance
        .post('/auth/login/', {
            username: process.env.USER,
            password: process.env.PASS,
            skipAuthRefresh: true,
        })
        .then((tokenRefreshResponse) => {
            failedRequest.response.config.headers.Authorization = `Token ${tokenRefreshResponse.data.token}`;
            return Promise.resolve();
        });
};
```

Thanks to Flyrell for answering this on [GitHub](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh/issues/72)